# Parsing JSON in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on my first experiment with React, trying to consume and display some data via an API that I also wrote (using the Django REST framework)

I am seeing the objects populate in the Console, but they don't render on the page.  I am also seeing an error in the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Which refers to line #18 in my ChangeList component:

```js
 import React from 'react';


 class ChangeList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
     this.state={items:[]};
   }
   componentDidMount(){
    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/backup/changes/1/Lead.json`)
    .then(result=>result.json())
   .then(items=>console.log(items) )
     .then(items=>this.setState( {items} ))
   }
   render() {
    return(
      <ul>
           {this.state.items.length ?
            this.state.items.map(item => <li> {item} </li>)
             : <li>Loading...</li>
           }
       </ul>
    )
   }
 }

 export default ChangeList
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

So how do I restructure this React component so that this.state.items.length is evaluated *after* all of the items are loaded?  Or am I still misunderstanding the issue, and if so, what am I doing wrong in rendering the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the `.then(items=>console.log(items))`, since `console.log()` returns `undefined`.

When `undefined` is returned, this line `.then(items=>this.setState( {items} ))` sets the state as `{ items: undefined }`, and `this.state.items` has no length property.

Just remove the `console.log()` statement or change it to:

```
.then(items=> { console.log(items); return items; })
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed the console.log() statement as you suggested but still nothing is rendered in the browser.  Also, there is no output to the console.  If I add back the console.log() statement with the changes that you suggested ( .then(items=> { console.log(items); return items; }) ) the objects are logged to the console, and there are no errors in the console (just the JSON Object) but still nothing renders in the UI.

Comment: What does a console.log(this.state) in render show?

Comment: I added console.log(this.state) to the render function (not sure if I did this correctly?  https://gist.github.com/joefusaro/4e09d0949e80dcbb1a02e01405dbc360 ) and now I'm seeing the following: http://imgur.com/a/C0SgG

Comment: In log you can see that the data is in `items.results`.  Make this change in your code `.then(items=>this.setState( {items} ))` --> .then(({ results })=>this.setState( {items: results} ))

Comment: Ah - that worked! I had previously tried accessing as items.results and items['results'] but those failed obviously.  Thanks for your help!  For anyone else following along, here is the final code: https://gist.github.com/joefusaro/4e09d0949e80dcbb1a02e01405dbc360

Comment: You're welcome :) btw - `{ items: items['results'] } ` should work as well.